# ASP.NET Async Webservice call problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a requirement in which i have to develop a page which runs a service on server calling through JavaScript. Now i also need to show updates about work being done(e.g Completed %).

Here's structure of my code.

```
    [WebMethod (true)]
    //Below method takes around 5-10 minutes in execution
    public string[] GenerateXMLSiteMap()
    {
      SiteMapGenerator siteMapGen = new SiteMapGenerator();
      siteMapGen.SiteMapNodeAddedSuccessfully += new  SiteMapNodeAdded(siteMapGen_SiteMapNodeAddedSuccessfully);
        siteMapGen.GenerateSiteMap();

        return GetStats();
    }

    void siteMapGen_SiteMapNodeAddedSuccessfully(string[] infos)
    {
        Session["CurrentPage"] = infos[0];
        Session["PageScanned"] = infos[1];
        Session["Time"] = infos[2];
    }

    [WebMethod (true)]
    public string[] GetStats()
    {
        string[] stats = new string[4];
        if (Session["CurrentPage"] != null)
        {
            stats[0] = Session["LinkDepth"].ToString();
            stats[1] = Session["CurrentPage"].ToString();
            stats[2] = Session["Time"].ToString();
        }

        return stats;
    }
```

I am calling GetStats() method from client-side but it is never invoked. I figured its because i am calling GenerateXMLSiteMap() which is still executing. Can anyone tell me how to get statics in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

WebMethod must be static and if you use MS Ajax you have to set the ScriptMethod attribute.

http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx